# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ViewSelector2' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am implementing analytics dashboard using Embed API and while executing the code for custom components from this link "https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/custom-components/"

I got this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ViewSelector2' of undefined".

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you are trying to access the `ViewSelector2` property of something that does not yet exist. You would get this error if you did something like this:

```
var myFunc = function()
{
     alert(obj.myProperty);
}
myFunc(); // calling function before object `obj` is being set
var obj = { myProperty: 'asdf' };
```

To fix this you would do this:

```
var myFunc = function()
{
     alert(obj.myProperty);
}
var obj = { myProperty: 'asdf' };
myFunc(); // calling function after object `obj` is being set
```

That's just an example. Since you have provided no code, I can't really help you more than that.